# get json data into li

Tags: jquery, json, html-lists, append

I have some Json data having an image of a product with some associated values. I want to get that json data, store it in 'li' and append to some div using jquery. Please tell me how to append image to the li. Here is the Json data

> {"url":"1.jpg","color":"Yellow","Item":"Item A","sold_out":"1"},{"url":"2.jpg","color":"Red","Item":"Item B","sold_out":"0"},{"url":"3.jpg","color":"Green","Item":"Item D","sold_out":"0"},{"url":"4.jpg","color":"Red","Item":"Item A","sold_out":"1"},{"url":"5.jpg","color":"Blue","Item":"Item B","sold_out":"0"}

Comment: What do you mean by "want to get"? Is it generated or do you need to generate it from the server?

Comment: It is in the local file items.json

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Is it in fact an array? `[{url:..., color:.........},{...}]`

Comment: I just need to know that if the json contains any image, then how we can append that image to the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the json using `$.each` and append it to the html element(li).

Example(***Not Tested***)

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $("ul").append("<li><img src=\"https://path/" + data[key].url+ "\" /></li>");
});
```

`data` is the json array.
Hope it helps.

Comment: yup just needed this.Thanks...

Comment: @user1690831 Welcome,Glad to see it helps u.

Comment: how to add other fields to the li

Comment: use data[key].color for color..like this u can display all the items in that json array

Comment: aah it's an array ... the OP didn't tell

Answer (score 1):

Append an image to a list

```
var myImageSrc = "1.jpg";
var myList = $('#mylist');
myList.append('<li><img src="' + myImageSrc + '" /></li>');
```

Comment: yeah this one is also what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle for what you wanted **UPDATE** http://jsfiddle.net/Rm4vE/4/